# Is it possible to validate that a property setter is being used? I'd like to know during the compilation phase or earlier

Tags: c#

In my code I'm doing validations within the Setter of a property. I'm looking for the opportunity to check if type properties has values.

My validation is the following:

```cs
public string SomeProperty
{
    get => _propValue;
    set
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNUll(value);
        _propValue= value;
    }
}
```

Now I would like to have additional validation, that would check and rise warning (or error) when the property's setter isn't called.

How can I solve this / write such validation?

Comment: Functions are not called during compilation, and neither are property setters. Compilation does not execute any code.

Comment: @Ken I might be misunderstanding, but I think OP wants to know if a setter is being used by their code or not.

Comment: I'm just curious, why is the question getting negative score? OP is asking whether this is possible and as it is not, he goes down?

Comment: @Tatranskymedved Possibly people misreading the title. I read it the same way as Ken did initially and had to re-read it to make sure I understood. I've edited it to be clearer.

Comment: If your aim is to prevent values being uninitialized at runtime, google for "nullable reference types". There's a compiler flag just for this purpose you can set in your project file.

Comment: Static analysis nowadays shows the number of references to methods and properties inline. But it's not separating getters and setters indeed. But other static analysis tools can site warnings like "... is read but never set". However, if setting depends on the program control fliw, i.e. depends on runtime, there's no way to determine that compile time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No with compiler and its default behavior: By default compiler does not provide any kind of checks in this way. Or better to say, we cannot mark the code anyhow, so that the compiler would understand "oh I should check whether this line has any references". Compiler (as of now - 24-05-2023) does not posses this functionality.

---

But... There is another level of solution (especially applicable with .NET and C#), where we are able to write own **Static analysis using Roslyn analyzers**.

There could be a good start to check this [official tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/tutorials/how-to-write-csharp-analyzer-code-fix) how to write one. There are some nice examples/tutorials on YT (e.g. here is [Mark Rendle talking about automatic generation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V4zqk4-LL1M) ). And there is [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/roslyn-analyzers-overview?view=vs-2022).

Answer (score 0):

> Now I would like to have additional validation, that would check and rise warning (or error) when the property's setter isn't called.

Sound like the reason for addition of the [`required`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/required) modifier in C# 11:

> The `required` modifier indicates that the field or property it's applied to must be initialized by an object initializer. Any expression that initializes a new instance of the type must initialize all required members. The `required` modifier is available beginning with C# 11. The `required` modifier enables developers to create types where properties or fields must be properly initialized, yet still allow initialization using object initializers

```cs
new Test(){ReqProperty = ""};

// will not compile:
// new Test(){};

public class Test
{
   public required string ReqProperty { get; set; }
}
```

[Demo @sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQTAjAsAULB2BTA7gAgCqIM4BcAUAlAN4BKiAjgAoBOA9gA6LU4CeqAvKgERcC+A3LFgB6YamQBLADZTU8WjlQBjWgFt60xAC4RYpGky5CRAUJggAzKnAZsOWEVipnl1NQoBXCe4Am1iAAMqGRUdIzMbESoAOaIOPyoWHEJvLC8QA=)